# IS there a way to use the Android AWS SDK to read file context from Amazon S3 bucket without having to download the file?

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

From the documentation i can see that you can download a file, but i was wondering is there a way to just get the content of a text file from an Amazon S3 bucket, without having to store the file locally ?

Comment: I don't think you'll need to store the S3 file locally but yes you'll definitely need to download the file in your memory to work on it. Here's the reference doc in Java: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `getObject()` on an instance of `AmazonS3` to download a file:

```java
String bucketName = "BUCKET_NAME";
String key = "KEY_OF_OBJECT";

AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION)
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .build();

System.out.println("Downloading an object");
S3Object fullObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
System.out.println("Content-Type: " + fullObject.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());
System.out.println("Content: ");

// fullObject.getObjectContent() is an InputStream 

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fullObject.getObjectContent()));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

If you only need part of the data, you can use the `withRange()` modifier on `GetObjectRequest()` to create a range request.